# Any software on Virtual Simulator?

Tags: simulation, debugging, electronics

May I know if there is any Virtual Equipment Simulator for download such as

1. Power meter
2. Spectrum analyser
3. Signal generator
4. Frequency translator

Any of the above would be fine. I would like to download it and do some testing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3354/software-for-simulating-electrical-circuits answer your question? If not what makes your question different?

Answer (score 1):

After reading your requirements the first product comes in my mind is [Multisim](http://www.ni.com/multisim/).

It is although a very big and large scale software and i haven't go through each of it's features particularly I've used it in my graduation for designing and simulating electronic circuits.

It is very good product developed by National Instruments and can handle your requirements.

It is not free but there is a [student edition](http://www.ni.com/multisim/student-edition/) and [trial version](http://www.ni.com/multisim/try/).

For starters [Tutorial](http://www.ece.mtu.edu/labs/EElabs/EE3010/revisions/Summer2009/Multisim%20Tutorial/MULTISIM%20Tutorial.pdf) and [Getting started](http://www.ni.com/multisim/technical-resources/).